# Validation of embedded forms with Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a `Parents` form embedded into another form `Student` containing the data of the parents of a student. I need to validate the embedded form, because in my code just makes the validation of another form.

StudentType.php

```
  //...
  ->add('responsible1', new ParentsType(),array('label' => 'Mother'))
  ->add('responsible2', new ParentsType(),array('label'=> 'Father'))

 /**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'BackendBundle\Entity\Student'
    ));
}
```

Entity Parents

```
 //...
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Student", mappedBy="$responsible1")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Student", mappedBy="$responsible2")
 */
 private $students;
```

Entity Student

```
 //...
 /**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Parents", inversedBy="students", cascade={"persist"})
 */
 private $responsible1;

/**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Parents", inversedBy="students", cascade={"persist"})
 */
 private $responsible2;
```

Using the following code in the controller I got the name and the error message of all invalid fields in the main form (`Student`), but I get get errors embedded forms (Parents), just get the name of the object (responsible1 or responsible2) and the message I get [object Object].

StudentController.php

```
protected function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) 
{
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
/**
 * Creates a new Student entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
// if request is XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) but not a POSt, throw an exception
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && !$request->isMethod('POST')) {
    throw new HttpException('XMLHttpRequests/AJAX calls must be POSTed');
}

    $entity = new Student();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Success!'), 200);
    }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

     if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
                    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'result' => 0,
        'message' => 'Invalid form',
        'data' => $this->getErrorMessages($form)),400);
    }

    return $this->render('BackendBundle:Student:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I tried the above code with the function `getErrorsAsString()` for errors in a string and so if they appear all, so I guess I'll have to add something in the above code to validate objects when "responsible1" or "responsible2" validate all fields.

I need to get all those errors are invalid fields on both forms.I read something to add `'cascade_validation' => true` , `validation_group` or `@Assert\Valid()` by the code, but I tried and I failed to get it. If someone can explain to me a little worth those, I thank you because I'm new to all this.

Comment: are you looking for a way to flattern error messages including nested forms ?

Comment: Hi @b.b3rn4rd, what I need is to validate a form and return with a JsonResponse an Ajax call and then indicate invalid form fields without refreshing the screen. This was a solution but I can not get the errors of the embedded forms.

Comment: makes sense, I was doing similar thing for ajax validation, posted a solution that works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following example flatterns form and subform errors into assoc array, let me know if this is what you are trying to achieve

```
<?php
namespace Example\Bundle\UtilityBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
class FormErrors
{
    public function getArray(Form $form, $style = 'KO')
    {
        $method = sprintf('get%sErrors', $style);

        $messages = $this->$method($form->all());

        return $messages;
    }

    private function getKOErrors(Form $children)
    {
        $errors = array();

        /* @var $child \Symfony\Component\Form\Form */
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $type = $child->getConfig()->getType()->getName();
            if ($child->count()  && ($type !== 'choice')) {
                $childErrors = $this->getKOErrors($child->all());
                if (sizeof($childErrors)) {
                    $errors = array_merge($errors, $childErrors);
                }
            } else {
                if (!$child->isValid()) {
                    // I need only one error message per field 
                    $errors[$child->getName()] = $child->getErrors()->current()->getMessage();
                }
            }
        }

        return $errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @b.b3rn4rd ,With your code I could get errors of the form was missing, but in my case, the form is embedded in the main twice. For me understand I have a student registration form and within me appears a registration form from the father and other data of the mother (both are of the same type). And what if I get any field is invalid both forms are the first fields.You need to somehow differentiate the errors obtained, for example responsible1_name or responsible2_name. I hope I explained well and thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Joseph, just add a second param `$name` to `getKOErrors(Form $children, $name)` and concatenate `$errors[$name.'_'.$child->getName() ]` and don't forget to pass it `->getName()` when calling

Comment: now everything works perfect, I believe that what I needed was to differentiate them, thank you very much, helped me a great help.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped